# How to block UI when post back happens?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've this requirement. To block web page while the server request is being processed, I am using jquery Block UI plugin and it is working as expected.
My problem here is I've to call BlockUI Everytime explicitly whenever any post back event like button click, dropdown index change. So if my application have let's say 25 forms consists of say 50+ controls wherein I've to Block UI Everytime the post back event occurs, I will have to call the block UI function 50+ times.

My requirement is, I will not have to call the block UI function explicitly and it should happen automatically that whenever any post back event is triggered UI should be blocked without explicit function call.

Can this be achieved?

Please help

Comment: Are you using ajax calls for each server request

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax call you can use global ajax event handlers, you can find here https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxStart handler." );
});
```

Comment: yes i am using ajax call. The line of code you have mentioned above, where do i need to put this in application?

Comment: @Swad add it in the top of your code within script tag, if it is working please mark it as working.

Comment: Do I need to put this in all pages in my application?

Comment: you can use it in header / footer codes which comes to all pages